# Retrieves big endian integer using addition

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have this macro

```
#define get32(buf) ((((*(buf))<<24)&0xff000000) + \
        (((*((buf)+1))<<16)&0x00ff0000) + \
        (((*((buf)+2))<< 8)&0x0000ff00) + \
        (((*((buf)+3)    )&0x000000ff)))
```

Which, to my understanding, assumes in `buff`, bytes are encoded in big endian way, and converts them to a 32 bit integer, right?

What confused me was that I was expecting `|` operator inside the macro instead of `+`?

Comment: provide code how buffer is written, as it explain things eaily

Comment: @Vineet1982: buffer bytes are unsigned, and if you feed in bytes stored in BE way, this macro works fine

Comment: `+` may work, but it is bad style.  Use `|` to combine bit fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is conventional and sane to use `|` but `+` works when everything is unsigned and the numbers to be added have disjoint ranges of bits. If the ranges of bits overlapped, then addition and logical or are not equivalent.

> Out of curiosity I was wondering how these functions are implemented when the integer is negative for example.

The way I'd probably implement the macro is:

```
#define get32(buf) ((((buf)[0] & 0xFF) << 24) | \
                    (((buf)[1] & 0xFF) << 16) | \
                    (((buf)[2] & 0xFF) <<  8) | \
                    (((buf)[3] & 0xFF) <<  0))
```

The main difference is that the lines are more systematic; the optimizer will eliminate the `<< 0` operation (probably even if the `-O` flag is not used).  This will handle negative numbers OK in practice (numbers where the high bit of `buf[0]` is set).

Comment: aa ok, btw. Do you know how people split integer into bytes when the integer is negative? I heard there maybe issues due to shift operators, etc.

Comment: The issue is mainly 'are `*buf` entries signed or unsigned', remembering that plain `char` may be signed or unsigned.  With the masking operations, everything there is pretty much safe either way; I don't see a way for it to go wrong, but you'll probably get information from others if I've forgotten or overlooked something.

Comment: No, in this case, the bytes are unsigned afaiac. Out of curiosity I was wondering how these functions are implemented when the integer is negative for example

Answer (score 0):

'+' is doing same thing as of | . for example:
number is 345678. while doing with +:

```
 340000
+005600
+000078
```

while doing with | kindly use bits:

```
 340000 [as bits]
|005600 [as bits]
|000078 [as bits]
```

seems there is no difference.